Creating/updating fields without create temporary files in QGIS Model Designer
So I'm starting with an "add layer" input, then a "refactor fields"

and I need the output to update the original layer I added in the "add layer" at the beginning.
So I want to add a lot is fields, and I don't want to do this one-by-one in the Field calculator. I want to automate it in the Model Designer.
I can't choose the added layer as output, and I can't understand why.
